# Form validation with onblur

Tags: forms, validation

Here is my form.

```html
<form method="post" name="frm">
    <label>Name*<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo $r['Name'] ?>" onblur="if(this.value.length<3) alert('Name too short');" /></label>

    <label>Username*<input type="text" name="UN" value="<?php echo $r['UN'] ?>" onblur="if(this.value.length<5) alert('Username too short');" /></label>
    <label>Password*<input type="password" name="PW"  onblur="validation()" /></label>
    <label>Confirm Password*<input type="password" name="CM" onblur="validation()" /></label>
    <?php } ?>

    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="<?php if($new) echo 'Register'; else echo 'Update'; ?>" />
</form>
```

Without writing separate *onBlur* events I am trying to get all these events into a function called `validation()` as I have done for *password* and *confirm-password* fields. Here is my validation function:

```html
<script language="javascript">
    function validation() {
        var password = document.frm.PW.value;
        var password2 = document.frm.CM.value;
            if (password.length < 5) {
                alert ("Password too short");
            }
            else if (password != password2) {
                alert("password mismatch");
            }   
     }
</script>
```

But with this code once I have filled password, and when I **am about to start** inputting for *confirm-password* field, it alerts the message "password mismatch". How to get rid of this? And for all the form tags if I am validating and using `validation()` function, then in each  tag do I have to call `onblur=validation()`?

Comment: If you replace the alerts with something that displays on the page as you type, much less annoying.  i.e. update a span with the error message.  I would avoid alerts, but if you do use them, save for when you click Submit.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have the password validation fired on the main password change - have it fired when you alter password2 or when you click submit. :)

If you insist on checking when you update password AND password 2, I would just add a check to see if password2 had been left blank:

```
else if(password !== password2 && password2 !== ""){
```

But doing ALL your checks on submit is a much cleaner solution (and as Rake says, it would be neater still to have a span that is updated instead of an alert).

Comment: That is without using onblur using <form method="post" name="frm" onsubmit="return validation()">